# UIActivityViewController for sending an sms with image, url and a text

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, iphone, uiactivityviewcontroller

I am using [UIActivityViewController](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiactivityviewcontroller) for sending an sms with image, URL and a text. But SMS is showing full url including all parameters, instead of a clickable short link.

```
NSURL *urlImage = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",imageUrl]];
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:urlImage];
UIImage *img = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:data];

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:shareURl];
UIActivityViewController *activityVC = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:@[@"I just won this on test. Check it out!", url, img] applicationActivities:nil];
activityVC.excludedActivityTypes = @[UIActivityTypeSaveToCameraRoll, UIActivityTypePostToFacebook, UIActivityTypePostToTwitter];
[self presentViewController:activityVC animated:YES completion:nil];
```

What I am getting is:

[image]+

What I need is:

[image]

Is there any way we can achieve this?